# Mapbox js - tileset colors assignment

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to create a colored uk areas map - I need the colors to be driven by local data (say for example sales by postcode), which will always change depending on user selections like report date ranges etc. I have a tileset source which I am assigning to a layer, as in the following (sensitive values blanked out):

```
         this.map.addLayer({
            "id": "uk-pc-data",
            "type": "fill",
            "source-layer": "***",
            "source": {
                type: 'vector',
                url: '***'
            }
        });
```

I am then able to style the postcode areas within the tileset by addressing a name property on the tileset features, like so:

```
           "paint": {
                "fill-color": [
                    "match",
                    ["get", "name", [{name: "PR"}, {name: "CH"}, {name: "LN"}]],
                    [
                        "PR",
                        "DD",
                        "AL",
                        "PO"
                    ],
                    "hsla(344, 84%, 29%, 0.37)",
                    "hsla(131, 94%, 34%, 0)"
                ]
            }
```

The above will assign one color to the matched areas, and a default to all the other (the non matched ones);  What I would like to do, is computing the colour value locally (so based on data constantly changing) based on the feature name, like so

```
            "paint": {
                "fill-color": function (feature = {}) {
                    return localSalesByArea(feature.name)
                }
            }
```

This though does not seem to be possible: any help or pointers appreciated; I have been through examples from Mapbox 
such as choroplet, heatmaps, expressions but these seem to rely on values delivered via the dataset itself (i.e Population), in my case the values which determine the color scale are separated (they come from an internal reporting api)

Answer (score 0):

If the data on which the colours are determined does not exist in the tileset, you basically have to do a gigantic lookup by name.

You will have a function that generates the `fill-color` expression, something like:

```
function makeFillExpression(valuesByName) {
    function valueToColor(value) {
        return /* insert your choroplething special sauce here */;
    }
    return ret = [
        "match",
        ["get", "name"],
        Object.keys(valuesByName).map(name => valueToColor(valuesByName[name])),
        'black'
    ];
}
```

Yes, it will be a very large and unwieldy expression.